# Mouth-Like Torus Animation

Tags: animation

I want to animate an object similar to a torus, like lips in the air.

What is the is the best way to do it? I try this way and the result at the top is not satisfactory.

[image]

Comment: maybe bad weight paint or not enough edge loops?

Comment: Yep.I learned to specify the weight of the vertexes manually and the result is much better.